# Grammatical reason for using "what" in "a technical medical term for *what* most people refer to as..."

Tags: relative-pronouns, which-what

Below is the question and the answer is "what."

> Xerosis is a technical medical term for ___ most people refer to as dry skin.

From my instinct, I understood why "what" should be an answer. The problem is I can't explain why "which" can't be an answer.

If I chose "which" for this question, then "which" indicated the word "term," but it couldn't be like that. I need an explanation based on grammar.

Comment: "Xerosis" is a medical term which means dry skin.   Xerosis is a medical term for dry skin.  Xerosis is a medical term for what people call dry skin.

Comment: The possible duplicate deals with 'what' and 'which' in questions.  This is different.

Comment: @sumelic - I've just been looking.  It's clearly relevant although rather weak on 'which'.  And the focus on 'fused relative noun phrases' is a bit diversionary here where the question is about when and how to choose between 'what' and 'which'.

Comment: @Dan: Isn't "what" called a "fused" relative because, as the definition you cited says, it means "that which, the thing which, something that"? I thought that is the explanation for the difference -- "what" can act grammatically like a "fusion" of a noun phrase + a relative pronoun, while "which" can't (except for in some very limited circumstances, apparently).

Comment: @sumelic - I think you are right.  I guess I think that F.E.'s answer explains how '*what*' can work but it does not really address *which*.  And the OP seems to me to be confused by how and when to use '*what*' and '*which*'.

Answer (score 2):

Your meaning can be communicated using either ***which*** or ***what*** -

> Xerosis is a technical medical term ***which*** most people refer to as dry skin.
>
> Xerosis is a technical medical term for ***what*** most people refer to as dry skin.

In the first case, ***which*** introduces an additional statement about the antecedent, the sense of the principal clause being complete without the relative clause; thus sometimes equivalent to ‘*and that*' (OED).

In the second phrase ***what*** means *that which, the thing which, something that* (OED).

In these examples, both *what* and *which* are relative pronouns.  Note, however, that they have different meanings/functions and may not simply be swapped. Both words have long histories and are used a great deal in a variety of ways!!

Comment: You have removed the word ***for*** in the first sentence.  ***which*** won’t work in OP’s sentence as stated.

Comment: @Jim - yes, I have.  The OP is having trouble deciding whether to use *what* or *which*.  It seems helpful to show how both words *may* be used to communicate the intended meaning and then to explain how they are different.

Comment: +1 for 'for what' = 'for the condition that' (OWTTE); the 'duplicate' doesn't address this.

Comment: So the reason for choosing 'what' is because of 'for?' As far as I understand, this preposition 'for' makes difference, and that's why you took away 'for' in the first sentence. Do I understand it in a right way?

Comment: Yes.  Using 'for' changes the sentence structure.